# rpmbuild failed after checking CHECK_RPATHS

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I've faced couple times with issue when rpmbuild failed after running check rpath. I cant understand when and why it happens. Now its okay running localy but when I run it in docker it fails. I don't see any specific error.
When rpmbuild is successful it check more rpath. For example good one is:

```
+ '[' '%{buildarch}' = noarch ']'  

+ QA_CHECK_RPATHS=1
+ case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
```

spec file:

```
%define app_home /usr/share/nginx/html/pmp
Name: pmp
Version: 0.0.2 
Release: 1%{?dist}
Summary: PHP application

Group: Applications/System
License: GPLv2+
URL: http://www.something/
Source: bin
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

%description

PHP application

%prep
%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{app_home}
rsync -vr --exclude 'rpm' %{_sourcedir}/ $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{app_home}/

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,nginx,nginx,-)
%{app_home}/*
```

after running rpmbuild which failed `rpmbuild -ba SPEC/my.spec`

`rpmbuild -ba --sign /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/SPECS/my.spec`

```
+ umask 022 
+ cd /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ exit 0
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ exit 0 
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64
+ dirname /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64
+ rm -rf /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-front-basket-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64/usr/share/nginx/html/pmp
+ rsync -vr --exclude rpm /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/SOURCES/ /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pmp-sprint10-1.el7.centos.x86_64/usr/share/nginx/html/pmp/

+ '[' '%{buildarch}' = noarch ']'
+ QA_CHECK_RPATHS=1
+ case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths

Paswwor12s

+ cp -u '/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/*' /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/SOURCES/rpm/
  cp: cannot stat '/home/makerpm/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/*': No such file or directory
+ exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been found. In .rpmmacross was specified noarch.

```
 %__arch_install_post \
  [ "%{buildarch}" = "noarch" ] || QA_CHECK_RPATHS=1 ; \
  case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in [1yY]*) /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths ;; esac \
/usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
```

Added the variable to the `*.spec` file and it's working now

```
BuildArch: noarch
```